# Is it advisable to ask the sponsor employer to pay for the Visa fee?

Tags: visa

I am extending my Tier 2 visa as advised by my sponsor(employer). But the company said that they only issue the Cos and asking me to pay the visa fee for me and my wife. Would it be possible if I could ask my company to bear the visa fee and health surcharges? Thank you.

Comment: Please specify country

Answer (score 7):

So the company told you that they would *not* pay the fee. It's not an open question, they already *told you*.

You want to ask them if they could pay the fee. Even when you already know their answer.

It's a free country, you can ask them. But they already told you they won't, why do you think they changed their minds? If I told somebody I will not pay for something and they come and ask me to pay for it, I would see it as negative. Does the person not listen to me?

From a purely psychological point, you will probably have more success to pay the fee yourself and ask for a raise later that is big enough so you can come out ahead anyway. Asking somebody for something they already denied is possible, but has a very low chance of success and is pretty pointless.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. One more clarification on my question, please bear with me. If the same rule implies even the employee is arrived in UK because the employer wants him on-site? Because, in my case I have been asked by my employer to work here and been advised to extend my visa as they need me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nisha It depends on who in the company told you they are not paying. Your manager and team leader might need you, but the corporate policy might simply be no. Its highly situational.

Comment: How can you say "it's a free country" when country was not specified?

Comment: " visa fee and health surcharges" are a UK thing so my guess was UK and the OP confirmed it in the comment above.

Comment: @David - It's a figure of speech.  It signifies the fact the author could have simply asked their employer since ultimately, it would come down to company policy.